# :first-of-type selector doesn't work

Tags: css, css-selectors

I can't explain why it is not working. I have the next HTML:

```
<div id="show-entrevistas-home">
  <div id="banner-lateral"></div>
  <div id="post-410" class="post-410 type-entrevistas status-publish hentry has-post-thumbnail"></div>
  <div id="post-408" class="post-408 type-entrevistas status-publish hentry has-post-thumbnail"></div>
  <div id="post-406" class="post-406 type-entrevistas status-publish hentry category-destacado has-post-thumbnail"></div>
</div>
```

and the next CSS:

```
#show-entrevistas-home div[id*='post-'].type-entrevistas:first-of-type {
   margin-top: 240px !important;    
}
```

The above CSS works when I remove `:first-of-type`, but it's not working with it (the first post is not getting the rule) . Any idea of what can be happening here with `:first-of-type`?

Comment: `div` tags are not closed in your code

Comment: @PranavRam - Sorry. It was due to copy - paste from Firebug

Comment: #banner-lateral matches with :first-of-type , your selector is only testing if first-of-type has an id starting with post and class type-entrevistas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `nth-child`:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Vppm7/3/)**

```
#show-entrevistas-home div[id*='post-']:nth-child(2) {
   margin-top: 240px;    
}
```

Comment: It's also applied to other child div elements.

Comment: So why did you originally want to use first-of-type? Do you want to apply it to all child elements except the first one?

Comment: No. Just to the second one (not the div inside it). Anyway, your answer works with: `#show-entrevistas-home div[id*='post-']:nth-child(2)`. If you update your answer I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 4):

Citing from the [MDN docu on `:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type):

> The :first-of-type CSS pseudo-class represents the first sibling of its type in the list of children of its parent element.

So it specifies *type*  and not *class* (or even whole selector). In your case the `:first-of-type` would refer to the `<div>` with class `banner-lateral`, whereas all the other selectors refer to the `<div>`s with the `post-x` classes.

The intersection of both is empty, hence your style rule never gets applied.

---

A workaround could be to change the type of the first `<div>` to something else. It seems that `<div>` should just hold a banner, so make it an `<img>` or use a `<span>` and adjust its behavior accordingly.

```
<div id="show-entrevistas-home">
  <img id="banner-lateral" />
  <div id="post-410" class="post-410 type-entrevistas status-publish hentry has-post-thumbnail"></div>
  <div id="post-408" class="post-408 type-entrevistas status-publish hentry has-post-thumbnail"></div>
  <div id="post-406" class="post-406 type-entrevistas status-publish hentry category-destacado has-post-thumbnail"></div>
</div>
```

or

```
<style>
  #banner-lateral {
    display: block; /* to make it behave like a div */
  }
</style>
<div id="show-entrevistas-home">
  <span id="banner-lateral"></span>
  <div id="post-410" class="post-410 type-entrevistas status-publish hentry has-post-thumbnail"></div>
  <div id="post-408" class="post-408 type-entrevistas status-publish hentry has-post-thumbnail"></div>
  <div id="post-406" class="post-406 type-entrevistas status-publish hentry category-destacado has-post-thumbnail"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So how would you do it?

Comment: @ManoloSalsas Couldn't you use `:first-child`

Comment: @ManoloSalsas If the structure is fixed you could work around with something like `:nth-child(2)`, but this would break immediately, when the structure changes. Or you could change the type of the first `<div>` to something else, which would make `:first-of-type` match the first post `<div>`.

Comment: This is an option, thanks. But it would get me into a mess. I prefer @Danield answer. Thanks anyway. +1

Comment: @ManoloSalsas As I said - both are options and will fail you in one way or the other, if you have to change your code in the future. :-)